# "It's done." or "It's been done."

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, present-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

When I just finished some work, which one below, A or B, is better to say and why?

A. It's done!
B. It's been done!

To me, A might sound simpler and more natural. But considering the grammar, I'm not sure if the simple present tense is appropriate here.

Comment: The both mean the same thing.  One is backward directed and said in the present right now and one is telling you that as of the time of speaking, the task is completed. It's a matter of emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a grammar issue.

It is an issue of rhetoric.

Q: Did you do it?
A: Yes, it's done.

The most emphatic for one thing that is done and finished at the time of speaking.

Q: Did you do it?
A: Yes, it's been done, [recently, lately, not so long ago]

The action is accomplished but when it was done is not important, just that it was in the past at the time of speaking.

Answer (score 0):

A. `It is done  or It's done` is used to refer to a work/job/process/task which is completed **recently** but it doesn't tell anything about the time when it was done.

**Example:** 
Manager asks - Did you complete the report? 
You - Yes, It is done.

whereas,

B. `It has been done` is  used when you want to use the passive voice instead of active voice in the sentence. **Here time reference is not required**.

**Example:**
Manager asks - Did you complete the report?
You - Yes, It has been done.

Both are correct.
Coming to your case.

If you have just finished your work, you can say:

**Okay! It's done.**

If it's been some time, you can go with:

**It's been done.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's done is passive, also.