# Is "has been done" used if it's done recently?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

[Here is the question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235071/its-done-or-its-been-done?rq=1) and I think it got wrong answer, isn't it?
As I said in the comment below the answer:
As I know present perfect used when action completed recently. 
And Simple past when earlier in the past. 
But the answer says the opposite.
I.e. I think "It has been done" if recently, and "It is done" if earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It is done" is in the present tense. "Done" in this sentence is an adjective, which refers to "it" (the work).

"It's done!" doesn't really suggest a time. It would depend on the context. If your boss is waiting for you to finish something, you might hand it to him and say, "Ok, it's done!" However, if your boss asks for a status report, you might say, "Yes, it's done," even if you finished it awhile ago. Or you could say, "It's been done" to indicate that you finished recently.