# How long is it? Vs How long has it been?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, present-perfect-progressive

1). How long is it since you were in London?

2). How long has it been since you were in London?

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: They look equivalent to me. The second is perhaps slightly more informal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["It's done." or "It's been done."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235071/its-done-or-its-been-done) (the answer in *this* question could be either Simple Present *It **is** a year* or Present Perfect *It **has been** a year*; both mean exactly the same thing).

Comment: "How long is it?" "[That's a rather personal question](https://youtu.be/GgT63yQtIHg)"

Answer (score 1):

> 1). How long is it since you were in London?
>
> 2). How long has it been since you were in London?

Both sentences have the same meaning. Also, both sentences are grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. They mean the same.

We usually say '**How long is it since.**..'

- 'How long is it since you were in London?' (=When were you in London?)
- 'It is four years since I was in London.'